# How to render partial from controller action (no JS ERB, just user render js: "command_string")

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know that in a controller action, as a JS response, instead of having a `.js.erb` template, I can directly run the JS command desired if it isn't too complicated. As an example:

```
respond_to do |format|
  # Delete the row from the table containing this user
  format.js{ render js: "$('#delete_#{user.id.to_i}').closest('tr').remove();" }
end
```

Note: The controller action needs to be called to perform database operations.

This saves me from creating a one line `.js.erb` file without dirtying my controller code. But when I try to use this to render a partial, I am simply not having any success. For example, in a `.js.erb` file, I would call it like this:

```
$('#emailform').html("<%= raw j(render partial: 'admin/email_form') %>");
```

But trying to use such a JS command from the controller doesn't work for me. My guess is that it is a string concatenation issue.

Is it possible to do what I want? Is it a good idea to want that in the first place?!

Comment: Do you mean something like this in your controller... render template: "admin/email_form"?

Answer (score 1):

These are the most relevant render options for controllers in rails, and since i don't fully understand your question you can decide for yourself which one is the best option for you:

```
render :edit
render action: :edit
render "edit"
render "edit.html.erb"
render action: "edit"
render action: "edit.html.erb"
render "books/edit"
render "books/edit.html.erb"
render template: "books/edit"
render template: "books/edit.html.erb"
render "/path/to/rails/app/views/books/edit"
render "/path/to/rails/app/views/books/edit.html.erb"
render file: "/path/to/rails/app/views/books/edit"
render file: "/path/to/rails/app/views/books/edit.html.erb"

render json: @product
render xml: @product
render html: "<strong>Not Found</strong>".html_safe
render js: "alert('Hello Rails');"
```

For more render options you can check out [this link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, this is not what I am looking for. I am sorry - I guess I wasn't clear enough as to what I wanted. I will update the question whenever I have the time.